# Incomprehensible conditional jump command in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

I trying to figure it out, i have these 3 line of assembly code:

```
cmp     [ebp+var_4], 7
lea     esi, [esi+0]
ja      loc_8048F2C
```

consider `var_4` is -4 and `ebp+var_4` is an address of an integer. `loc_8048F2C` is a label.

Well, I dont understand when the `ja` (jump if above) command will work. Doesnt the `lea` command change the flags (like `ZF` `SF` etc...) ? I thought each command in assembly change the flags, am I right?

In other words: if my integer is greater than 7, are we jump to `loc_8048F2C` or not?

Comment: the best guess you can do is that your hypothesis "doesn't the lea command change the flags" is wrong; ja uses CF and ZF, and lea does not affect flags

Comment: No, LEA doesn't change the flags.  But you could have looked this up yourself easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the LEA instruction doesn't change flags. It is put between `CMP` and `JA` so while the processor is busy reading from memory to perform the comparison, it can execute the `LEA` instruction, that has no dependencies with neither the previous or the following instruction.

Hopefully, when `JA` instruction is reached, the processor will have the results of CMP ready and no delay will be added.

Answer (score 2):

Not all opcodes modify flags. The `lea` instruction is one that does not. The flags set by `cmp` will still have the same value with `ja` is executed.

Comment: In this case, `lea` not only doesn't modify flags, it doesn't even modify `esi`! Its only purpose is for padding, to put subsequent instructions at a favorable alignment - same as multiple `nop`s, only faster. The source code probably says `align` not `lea ...`.